# React - Setting state immediately after an async action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

So I have a button. When you click on that button, it takes you to an onSubmit function which looks like this:

```
  onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.nextSentence(); //this is async

      this.setState({ //this is not yet updating with the right values then
          inputField: this.props.activePupil.name
      });
  }
```

However: `this.props.nextSentence();` is async, so when I set my state immediately after, there are no changes. Right now I have a second button which refers to a second function which just sets the state again. I would like to have this happen automatic though. How could I do this?

Comment: why don't you want for the result and then set state? using then(...)

```this.props.nextSentence.then(value => this.setState ({ ... }))```

Comment: Perhaps you can try to set your state as a props and change it in the parent that contain the callback nextSentence ?

Comment: You can use promises to handle this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

async actions are normally either `Promises` or `functions with callbacks`.

In case of a `Promise` you need to use `.then` like below

```
this.props.nextSentence().then(() => {
  this.setState({...});
})
```

And in case of a `function with callback`

```
this.props.nextSentence(() => {
  this.setState({...})
})
```

However keep in mind than you can get the returned response of your async action and use it to update your state. which is normally the case.

For example

```
//here response is a json object returned from server     
this.props.nextSentence().then((response) => {
  this.setState({
    data: response.data
  });
})
```

Comment: thank you. `However keep in mind than you can get the returned response of your async action and use it to update your state. which is normally the case.` - how would this differ from using promises or callbacks?

Comment: It is exactly the same you just use your async method response to change your state like the example I provided.