# How to turn redux-thunk action creator into Promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, redux

I have the following async action creator (using redux-thunk):

```
export const nextPupil = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {activeSentence, sentencesList} = getState();
    //... some more code
    const nextActive = pupilList[nextIndex];

    dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_ACTIVE", payload: nextActive });
  }
};
```

However, I need this action to return a promise, since I need to wait for its completion in one of my components, before doing something else (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092299/react-setting-state-immediately-after-an-async-action/43092479#43092479) for a more detailed description of my problem)

How could I turn this action into a promise and still use redux-thunk? Thanks a lot in advance.

edit:

I am aware that I am trying to save the state of the input field locally in my component, i.e., not in Redux. This because if I were to bind the value of the input field directly to the redux store, it would not be editable anymore. However, I want the user to be able to edit the input field and then, on submit, save the edited value in my redux store. If I bind things directly, the user won't be able to change values / edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the data flows through redux.  I assume when you want to turn the action into a promise, you would want that promise to resolve when the redux state has been updated - this appears to be the case from your other question.  This is not generally how redux is designed to work.

When you dispatch an action, the store will be updated, and then the props in your components that come from the store will update.  All you need to do is use those props in your components, and whenever the props update, so will your component.

In your initial question your code was:

```
onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.props.nextSentence(); //this is async

  this.setState({ //this is not yet updating with the right values then
      inputField: this.props.activePupil.name
  });
}
```

The issue you have is that `activePupil` is part of your redux store, yet you are trying to store it within the state of your component as well.  This is a bad idea because you no longer have a single source of truth for your state.

The better approach is to just use `this.props.activePupil` wherever it is needed, e.g.

```
 render() {
     return (
        <span>{this.props.activePupil.name}</span>
     );
 }
```

Now when you dispatch the action, as soon store is updated, your component will also update.  If you need to then you can add a `loading` property to your store, so that you can indicate to the user that something is happening, and dispatch this from your thunk before doing any async work, and then revert `loading` when `UPDATE_ACTIVE` is dispatched.

```
export const nextPupil = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch({ type: "PUPIL_UPDATING });
      const {activeSentence, sentencesList} = getState();
      //... some more code
      const nextActive = pupilList[nextIndex];

      dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_ACTIVE", payload: nextActive });
  }
};
```

## Edit 1

It's taken a bit of thinking about the right approach to your issue below, but I think I have settled on a reasonable way to achieve it, while maintaining data integrity.  It does involve keeping form input in your store, which not everyone is a fan of, but is not a problem for me.

Anyway... we need another reducer for handling user input - it will be very simple and respond to two actions - the "UPDATE_ACTIVE" action you already have, and an "NAME_UPDATED" action:

```
const updatedName = (state = '', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_ACTIVE':
        return action.payload.name;
    case: 'NAME_UPDATED':
        return action.payload.updatedName;
    default:
        return state;
  }
};
```

Then we will need a simple action creator:

```
const inputChanged = updatedName => ({
     type: 'NAME_UPDATED',
     payload: { updatedName }
});
```

Now within our component we will use the newly created state and action creator to manage our input (just `connect` them in as per usual) - lots of code missing here but there should be enough to get the idea.

```
class Whatever extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.props.inputChanged(event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" value={this.props.updatedName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        );
    }
}
```

I hope that makes sense!

## Edit 2:

If you want to store the input on component state rather than within the redux store, then I think this approach should work.  It uses the [componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle hook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) - to set the component state i.e. the input value when the `activePupil` prop changes.  This is called every time the props update, but may also be called when there aren't any prop changes, so we need some logic to decide whether to update the `updatedPupilName` prop.  To achieve this we are comparing our current `props.activePupil.name` to the `nextProps.activePupil.name` and only updating the state if they are different.  If you have an ID type property on your pupils this would probably be better suited for the comparison.

```
class Whatever extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            updatedPupilName: props.activePupil.name
        };
        this.handleChange= this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.activePupil.name !== this.props.activePupil.name) {
            this.setState({
                updatedPupilName: nextProps.activePupil.name
            });
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            updatedPupilName: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" value={this.state.updatedPupilName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really well explained answer, nice job :)

Comment: thanks a lot for the elaborate answer! My problem is, that when I use `this.props.activePupil.name` directly, it will not be editable for the user, as it will be bound to the redux store's value. But I want the user to be able to change the value of the input field and save this in the store. This is why I set a state of the input field inbetween the two, and put the store's value into the input field, and on submit want to save that again to the store. Or am I misunderstanding this gravely?

Comment: thank you! it really is incredibly helpful! I have been struggling with this for days now.

Comment: I've updated my question, putting the focus more on the problem of the editable textfield.

Comment: Took a but of reflection to decide on the best approach, but I've updated my answer now.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate this so much. I'm not sure I understand though. So the basic idea behind all of this is to put everything into props and have no local state anymore? I am also not sure what this is supposed to do exactly: `value={this.props.updateName}` - what does this reference? The action creator & reducer are called `updatedName` - is this a mistake, or did you choose to use a different name? Also, do we have to create a separate reducer for this? Could I not simply use my activePupil reducer?

Comment: Yes sorry my mistake it should be `this.props.updatedName`.  You can use a different reducer or add a new property into an existing reducer, it shouldn't really matter either way.

Comment: And yes everything is going in the redux store rather than component state.  I'm not a zealot who wants to eliminate component state in favour of redux, but when I was thinking over solutions things were going to get very over-complicated with lifecycle methods to keep the component state up to date if we kept it in the component  Although keeping in the redux store adds some boilerplate, I think it is easier to reason about.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, it seems very complicated to me and it seems to make the code very spaghetti like. It might be because I'm a beginner that it appears to me this way. Also, I have tried to implement it and it didn't work, but I'm not sure exactly what might be wrong. But thank you anyways, it really helped me understand things better. But what is still on my mind is: why can we not just use the internal state of the component, and then re-render that component after `nextPupil()` has finished?

Comment: The only way we can tell from within the component that `nextPupil()` has finished is when the props that component receive are updated.  I've added an example to my answer that keeps the input state internal to the component, and uses the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook to update this state when the activePupil prop changes.

Comment: thank you so much. makes much more sense to me like this. You really helped me out with this one, I struggled for such a long time! Thank you so much!